# Is it possible to stop SWIG generating the module class for Java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I've created a C++ class that I want to be able to construct and call methods on from Java.

Here it is (in a file called test_swig_cpp_java.h):

```
#ifndef TEST_SWIG_CPP_JAVA_H_
#define TEST_SWIG_CPP_JAVA_H_
class GoOnJavaConstructMe {
public:
    void oohComeOnCallMeYouKnowYouWantTo();
};
#endif
```

I then created a module file for SWIG (called test_swig_module.i) and put this in it:

```
%module Test;
%ignore "";
%rename("%s") GoOnJavaConstructMe; 
%rename("%s") GoOnJavaConstructMe::oohComeOnCallMeYouKnowYouWantTo; 
%{
    #include "test_swig_cpp_java.h"
%}
%include "test_swig_cpp_java.h"
```

I ran the following command to get SWIG to do its stuff:

```
swig -c++ -java test_swig_module.i
```

And listed the files I had in the directory that were not the two I created - here is the list:

```
GoOnJavaConstructMe.java
Test.java
TestJNI.java
test_swig_module_wrap.cxx
```

Great, so I have a cxx (`test_swig_module_wrap.cxx`) file that I need to compile in with my C++ code and on the Java side, the class I want to call has been nicely created (`GoOnJavaConstructMe.java`) and I can see some JNI declarations (`TestJNI.java`) that I also need to compile in with my Java gubbins.

Seems OK so far but what is `Test.java` I wonder ... when I open it, it looks like this:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
 * Version 3.0.2
 *
 * Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
 * the SWIG interface file instead.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


public class Test {
}
```

An empty class with the same name as the SWIG module, interesting...So I did some [research](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_module_packages_classes) and I see that this is called the *module class* and it is a place where global functions are put.

Right, fair enough, I suppose they gotta go somewhere but then I thought, the thing is, I will never have any global functions as I am being very specific that I want to expose only a single class and method to Java.

I *could* put a step in my build process that deletes this file after I run SWIG, of course, but then I idly wondered...

**Is it possible to stop SWIG generating the module class for Java?**

*(there doesn't seem to be a [command line option](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_commandline) for this as far as I can tell so I figure the answer is probably no, but maybe the gurus on SO know of a clever trick perhaps in the module file)*

Comment: I think the solution is to delete the file if you don't want it and it's empty.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Flexo, that is what I have done but just wondered if I could stop it getting created in the first place.  Seems not.